# Spring boot + Axis2 webservice : server unknown

Tags: spring, tomcat, soap, spring-boot, apache-axis

I have a Spring boot axis2 (1.6.2) application in *.aar packaging.it is currently deployed to a tomcat container (with axis2 extracts inside tomcat's webapps folder).i copied the .aar inside axis2 services folder.
I am able to hit the service and the wsdl is also shown.
But when i send a soap request it fails with

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
        <detail />
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I have the services.xml and wsdl file under meta-inf in resources folder.
services.xml has the class that extends org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver
i referred to this documentation.
https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html
(I even disabled the embedded tomcat)

Regard
chandru